# Can I use an aliased domain for Google OAuth consent email

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth

I have a Google Workspace account with a primary domain `business-name.com` and an aliased domain for my app `app-name.com`. I have also created the email alias `support@business-name.com` and `support@app-name.com`, both of which point to a single user `my.name@business-name.com`.

My app, `app-name`, uses Google OAuth for sign in, but I'd like the consent popup to reference `support@app-name.com` rather than my personal address at the primary domain.

When I create an additional user in Google Cloud IAM, I can specify `support@app-name.com`, but the console always resolves this back to `my.name@business-name.com` and the consent popup always displays the primary user/domain.

If I replace the email alias `support` with a Group, a similar thing happens; `support@app-name.com` is published as the primary `support@business-name.com`

Is there any way to get the Google OAuth consent screen to publish and aliased email address?